# How to make my models follow DRY principles

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model in which I need to represent different jobs for a labor application, for example:

```
from django.db import models

class PostFirstJobAd(models.Model):
    fist_job_ad_title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    first_job_ad_description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class PostSecondJobAd(models.Model):
    second_job_ad_title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    second_job_ad_description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class PostThirdJobAd(models.Model):
    third_job_ad_title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    third_job_ad_description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Instantly you can see that I'm repeating `title`, `description` and `created_at`, I'm just changing field's name, it's not DRY and code is starting to *smell*. The reason for this is because I want to register every job separately inside `django admin`, so I will have clear situation inside site administration.

One way to make them DRY is to use `Abstract base classes` but I have a problem because from the docs:

> This model will then not be used to create any database table.
>   Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields
>   will be added to those of the child class.

What will be the right approach in this case, can someone help me understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using abstract base models:

```
class JobAd(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class PostFirstJobAd(JobAd):
    pass

class PostSecondJobAd(JobAd):
    pass

class PostThirdJobAd(JobAd):
    pass
```

This would create 3 tables.  The base class JobAd does not have a table in the db.

Since you appear to have 3 different models with the exact same code, you should question whether you really need 3 different models at all.  Another option is to just store them all in one table, and add another field for the "other" thing.

```
class JobAd(models.Model):
    pos = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=['first', 'second', 'third'])
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

An integer field for `pos` is also possible.

Comment: I was questioning that, I need to represent six different jobs, and the reason I want them to be separate is, because I want to have clear situation inside admin, I don't want my applicants to apply in one model, so for every job one application, I hope you understand me

Comment: Rethink your design. You really don't need separate models.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the abstract models *might* be what you need here. Depending on the business requirements, you may need to think a little harder on the architecture.

If, in fact, you do need to use abstract base classes:

```
class BaseJob(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # etc...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def method_1(self):
        # base methods that work for instance data
```

Once that is defined, you can implement the base class in a concrete model. A concrete model is a model that doesn't use the `abstract = True` metaclass property (or proxy, etc.) like so:

```
class Job(BaseJob):
    pass
```

If you need additional fields you can define them like any other model field but when you run `makemigrations` you'll find the fields get added in the migration generated.